# Why do zygotes divide internally and not externally?

Tags: embryology, mitosis

As far as I understand, two gametes fuse to create a zygote. Gametes are created via miosis, they are haploid and when they fuse they become a complete cell (diploid). And diploid cells divide via mitosis.

However, I wonder why a zygote does not become two zygotes? What is different about it that makes it divide internally?

In other words, why does a liver cell become two separate cells, yet the zygote becomes two cells inside the same shell?

[image]

**Update**:

Maybe this image can help:

[image]

The zygote is dividing. But what is that external package? Why do those divided cells remain in a circular sac (Sorry for this stupid terminology, I want to make myself clear)?

But in simple mitosis (the image below) divided cells are not inside a package anymore. They are 100% separate from each other.

[image]

As I have understood it, the divided cell remains in the parent tissue. A liver cell after division becomes two cells inside the liver. The container is the liver.

However, the zygote is not like that. It's internal mass divides and remains inside the same zygote. I don't know what's so hard about understanding this for your guys.

Maybe the zygote is not the outcome of the fertilization of the egg and sperm. Maybe an egg has a package and a cell inside it, and that package is not part of the cell. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: What do you mean "inside the same shell"? Zygotes divide just like liver cells...

Comment: look up monozygotic twins

Comment: It seems that I'm missing something here. Maybe a zygote is not a cell. Maybe it's a biological envelope, containing a cell, and then the inner cell divides. But the `monozygotic twins` images do not show that. Bot inner cells, and the envelope divide.

Comment: @BryanKrause, please look at [this](https://www.genome.gov/sites/default/files/media/images/tg/Identical-twins.jpg) image for example. The inner cell (blue dot) divides, and the outer shell also divides.

Comment: What do you mean by "shell" a zygote divides into two sperate cells just like all cell divisions. Are you maybe thinking of the corona radiata, which breaks down after fertilization.

Comment: If the term zygote is a diploid cell, then when it divides there is nothing strange in the fact that it becomes two diploid cells. If the term zygote indicates its special origin, it is impossible logically for a daughter cell to have the same origin. Your expectation that the zygote would divide into two haploid gametes seems bizarre. The “magic” thing would seem to me to be meiosis and fusion. Once you have a zygote it’s not quite back to normal because the cell must differentiate, but mitosis is the default cellular behaviour.

Comment: If you don't understand the parts of an illustration you should probably ask about that before guessing and asking a confusing question based on your guess.

Comment: @John, then please clarify my misunderstanding instead of criticising me. Thank you.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati its not criticism its how questions work, the site is for answering specific questions

Comment: @John, is the image I have shown up not clear? What can not be understood from that image?

Comment: You have half  dozen questions here, I will answer one, that outer membrane is called the zona pellucida. it exists to control fertilization. https://study.com/learn/lesson/early-embryonic-development-human-stages-formation-mechanisms.html

Comment: @John, so I was right. The egg is not a cell. It's a cell inside a package. The Zona Pellucida is not part of the normal cell that divides. It acts as the container for the fetus and placenta.

Comment: No it breaks open long before either is formed, again research don't guess.

Comment: @John, please don't be harsh. Either help or leave this question for others to answer. I have watched dozens of videos regarding this. I have done my research to ask this question. And you just complicate things. So either help or please leave.

Comment: I'm complicating it by trying to lead you to asking a coherent question instead of just voting to close for asking several separate questions. Or at least figure out where your confusion is coming from.  there is no difference between liver cells and zygote cell division. a liver cell divides into 2 separate liver cells and a zygote divides into 2 separate zygote cells. A dividing liver cell does not become 2 livers why would a dividing zygote cell become 2 zygotes? if you want to know about the function of the Zona Pellucida ask that as a question. You could also look into cell adhesion.

Comment: this may help you https://www.twins.org.au/how-to-determine-zygosity/89-placenta and https://twinstudies.org/zygosity-and-chorionicity-of-twins/